# play the range of big WMV files by using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, range, wmv, playback

I am developing a ASP.NET by using c#.net and  have many  WMV files and have to watch the range of the file which I gave.The size of  files are too big also   the users shouldn't download the all of the file , should download between the range which I give . Is there anybody to help me ?

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. Is it as follows:
You have several WMV files (each say 20 minutes long when played).

Are you now wanting to allow users to download a portion of each file? Say 5 minutes long.

Or are you wanting to stream the video to the user from any point within the WMV?

Comment: Yeah, I'm wanting to stream the video to the user from any point within the WMV. My Videos are bigger than 1 GB and user want to see interested position so I want to go specified point programmatically.

I mustn't convert to FLV. File must be WMV file.
An I have not any idea how can I do :(
I try something with FileStream but :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since WMV files have a header at the beginning and an index at the end you can't just use a FileStream to deliver partial files, for that "streaming" formats like MPEG1/2 or H.264 are much better.

For partial WMV file streaming I would investigate in

[Microsoft Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/webserver.aspx)

This will basically do the job for you, although if you want tight control over the offsets you want to stream from you will have to dynamically create playlists for your files (i.e. see Server side playlists)